# Can i use email/password combination for oauth2 authorization in server to server java application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

while reading through oauth docs,i couldnt find an example to use one's gmail username and password in oauth2 authorisation flow for server-server call.
my app is running on appengine,I want to use contacts API to add contacts to my acccount. How is this possible because oauth2 authorises an application(service account) and not me (user who created(owner) this application). If i create a contact it will be added to service account.How do i add a new contact using contacts API to my email account

Comment: no. user and password is not supported in oauth2, only oauth1 for all google apis.

Comment: question is too broad. read an in depth guide on oauth2

Comment: @Zig Mandel my specific question is :if i use the client_secrets.json or clientid and client secret to get a GoogleCredential object reference,will it authorise my application for service account or the user(email id used to create this) who owns the application

Comment: sorry too broad and missing details. see an oauth2 guide.